# Android - Home Screen Life Cycle

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen, android-launcher

I am developing an Android Home Screen, I seem to be experiencing problems. Whenever I start an application from that home screen, its lifecycle ends up to being destroyed(I Knew this because I used LogCat and it does print my code in the OnDestroyed method). I only want it to only be paused not completely destroyed because I am running a little long processes in the oncreate. I only wanted the onCreate to be called once, which is when the device boots. In my case, since whenever my home screen starts an application, it is destroyed. And whenever I press the HOME button, it goes through from on create -> on start -> on resume. 
The following is my codes, can you state if I am doing something wrong. Thanks.

My Code in Starting an Application:

```
public void startAppByAppName(String appName) {
    String mainActivity = "";
    String packageString = "";

    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
    mainActivity = intent.getComponent().getClassName();
    packageString = intent.getComponent().getPackageName();

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageString, mainActivity));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:persistent="true">
    <activity 
        android:name="com.steven.welcomescreen.WelcomeScreenActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

If there is some parts of my code which you want to clarify, just comment below so I could supply you with information. I really need help. Thanks you very much.

Comment: remove the flag